# How do I load different view controller for older devices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The new version of my app depends on iOS 5.0+. However, my old version allowed iOS 4. If I remember correctly, Apple will reject the app if it removes support for some users. I am trying to have devices not on iOS 5.0+ load another XIB called `oldVersion`. Here's what I've tried:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version < 5.0) {
    UIViewController *olderVersion = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"oldVersion" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = olderVersion;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
} else {
    //Load normally.
}
```

(This is in the app delegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`)

---

I've also tried loading my new version and

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version < 5.0) {
    oldVersion *screen = [[oldVersion alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:NO];
    [screen release];
    return;
} else {
    //Normal stuff...
}
```

in my `viewDidLoad`. Neither of them works properly. The first one (in app delegate) loads the screen but does not load anything in the code (like NSLog() and UIAlertView's). The second one (viewDidLoad) does not show up the screen, it just loads my new version without any of the customization I do in code.

So, how do I send devices not on iOS 5.0+ to `oldVersion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Apparently, all I had to do was wait a little (I am using 0.1) before displaying the new XIB. So it is now:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(usersOnOldVersionsOfiOSReallyNeedToUpgradeToiOS5OrHigherToUseThisVeryCoolApp) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

where `usersOnOldVersionsOfiOSReallyNeedToUpgradeToiOS5OrHigherToUseThisVeryCoolApp` opens up the XIB for > iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

in the viewDidLoad, Check the version and log it to the nsuserdefaults, so you don't have to check it every time. then load the new view.

Comment: That won't change anything. Also, why should I save it? What if the users upgrades his/her device.

Answer (score 0):

You might check if an object implements a method that is only available on newer versions of the OS. This is a common way of checking the current runtime environment. Eg:

```
if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector(userInterfaceLayoutDirection)] ) {
    // userInterfaceLayoutDirection is only available in iOS 5+
    // use 5.0+ version of xib
}
```

I believe you can also check if the address of a constant is not nil, and derive the OS version from that:

```
if ( &UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey != nil ) {
    // UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey is only available in iOS 5+
    // use 5.0+ version of xib
}
```

Comment: I can already detect if the user is running >  iOS 5. Anyway, thanks for your time. I already solved it.